Window Weather stripping question
Hi I got a question about what type and what window Weather stripping would be good for a casement crank window. I noticed a draft coming through them and have decided to change them.
What type of weather stripping is this and Where would I get it.
Or any alternatives
Attached are photos of the original weatherstripping.
https://ibb.co/nwwnJxn
https://ibb.co/4sH35Mj
https://ibb.co/g3Yw6vx
https://ibb.co/GThT3bX
https://ibb.co/19wLf0M
https://ibb.co/3v0B5j4

Your photos are missing the most important part, a clear picture of the base of the weather-stripping fitting into the groove (kerf) of the window frame.

I can't make sense of those pictures. Gaps between the window and the rough opening can be filled with foam weather strip like here: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-0-375-in-x-20-in-Grey-Poly-Foam-Tape-Weatherstrip-Caulk-Saver-C21H/100067266

This is backer rod. It may be short term solution but does not solve the problem.
